# How to make a Blazor page update the content of one html tag with incoming data from gRPC service

Tags: grpc, blazor

So i'm testing with Blazor and gRPC and my dificulty at the moment is on how to pass the content of a variable that is on a class, specifically the gRPC GreeterService Class to the Blazor page when new information arrives. Notice that my aplication is a client and a server, and i make an initial comunication for the server and then the server starts to send to the client data(numbers) in unary mode, every time it has new data to send. I have all this working, but now i'm left it that final implementation.

This is my Blazor page

```
@page "/greeter"
@inject GrpcService1.GreeterService GreeterService1


@using BlazorApp1.Data

<h1>Grpc Connection</h1>

<input type="text" @bind="@myID" />
<button @onclick="@SayHello">SayHello</button>


<p>@Greetmsg</p>
<p></p>

@code {
    string Name;
    string Greetmsg;


    async Task SayHello()
    {
        this.Greetmsg = await this.GreeterService1.SayHello(this.myID);

    }

}
```

The method that later receives the communication from the server if the hello is accepted there is something like this:

```
public override async Task<RequestResponse> GiveNumbers(BalconyFullUpdate request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            RequestResponse resp = new RequestResponse { RequestAccepted = false };
            if (request.Token == publicAuthToken)
            {
                number = request.Number;
                resp = true;
            }
            return await Task.FromResult(resp);
}
```

Every time that a new number arrives i want to show it in the UI.

Another way i could do this was, within a while condition, i could do a call to the server requesting a new number just like the SayHello request, that simply awaits for a server response, that only will come when he has a new number to send. When it comes the UI is updated. I'm just reluctant to do it this way because i'm afraid that for some reason the client request is forgotten and the client just sit's there waiting for a response that will never come. I know that i could implement a timeout on the client side to handle that, and on the server maybe i could pause the response, with a thread pause or something like that, and when the method that generates the new number has a new number, it could unpause the response to the client(no clue on how to do that). This last solution looks to me much more difficult to do than the first one.
What are your thoughts about it? And solutions..

##################### UPDATE ##########################

Now i'm trying to use a singleton, grab its instance in the Blazor page, and subcribe to a inner event of his.

This is the singleton:
public class ThreadSafeSingletonString
{
private static ThreadSafeSingletonString _instance;
private static readonly object _padlock = new object();
private ThreadSafeSingletonString()
{

```
        }

        public static ThreadSafeSingletonString Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    lock(_padlock)
                    {
                        if (_instance == null)
                        {
                            _instance = new ThreadSafeSingletonString();
                            _instance.number="";
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                return _instance;
            }
            set
            {
                _instance.number= value.number;
                _instance.NotifyDataChanged();
            }
        }
        public int number{ get; set; }

        public event Action OnChange;

        private void NotifyDataChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
```

And in Blazor page in code section i have:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        threadSafeSingleton.OnChange += updateNumber();
    }

    public System.Action updateNumber()
    {
        this.fromrefresh = threadSafeSingleton.number + " que vem.";
        Console.WriteLine("Passou pelo UpdateNumber");
        this.StateHasChanged();
        return StateHasChanged;
    }
```

Unfortunatly the updatenumber function never gets executed...

Comment: you should have a look at https://damienbod.com/2019/03/25/grpc-bi-directional-streaming-with-razor-pages-and-a-hosted-service-grpc-client/

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you. Unfortunately, that doesn't seems what i'm looking for.
I would like to trigger the refresh of the page or page element from the singleton that holds the data and has a event Action OnChange.

Comment: Do you have a proto file for the service you want to access? If yes please post it so I may help you more.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for you patience and willing to help. I've updated the question because now i know i cannot update directly the pages that are being anded to the browsers by the http service. Now i'm using the siglteon aproach and trying to subscribe to an event of his but is not working. Do you see what i'm doing wrong? Maybe this is also a bad concept.
About the gRPC service it's all ok, it is working well.
Se the updated question.

Comment: Im not really undestand your change, _Unfortunatly the updatenumber function never gets executed_ yes I do not see where you call it or what else should call it. If you have a proto file for the gRPC Stub please post it so I can understand.

Comment: That line on the OnInitialized should call, right??
Here goes proto:
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcConsole";

package Greet;

// The greeting service definition.
service NumberManagement {
  //Say hello
  rpc SayHello(Name) returns (HelloName);
  rpc SendNumber(number) returns (NumberReceived); 
}

message Name{
    string name =1;
}
message HelloName{
    string name =1;
}
message number{
    IdMessage identification = 1;
}
message NumberReceived{
    bool RequestAccepted=1;
}

Comment: IdMessage is not difines so I changed it to string for usage see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To force a refresh of the ui you can call the `StateHasChanged()` method on your component:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.statehaschanged?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> Notifies the component that its state has changed. When applicable, this will cause the component to be re-rendered.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for trying to help. I'm trying to do that but i dont have any way to make the blazor page do that from the singleton that i use to pass the data from my gRPC service into the blazor page. In the Blazor page i even tried to make a link to the singleton event Action OnChange to try the UI to be updated, but it doesn't work either. That code is only executed when i navigate to another page and back...

Comment: Oh I think I understand a little better now - you have something on your server that updates and you essentially want to send a message to the page to say "I have a new one of these things, you need to update", this is basically what signal r does, but I'm not sure how well it plays with blazor

Comment: Well, not quite that. What i mean by a server, is a gRPC server, that only serves data by gRPC protocol. It doesn't have UI. I have another application that is a gRPC client and has Blazor as UI. It serves the page to the browser, wich is a client in that mater, but this second application core is to be the cliente of the gRPC server. And this application, after registering in the gRPC server machine, stays quietly listening to data send from that machine. When that data comes in, i want the page that is handled by the gRPC client machine to be updated. That page is in Blazor.

Comment: Hi Mark. I tried to implement a singleton and an observer/subscriber to a change event inside that singleton but it doesn't works either. The function updateNumber in the Blazor page never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Request**

After fully understanding that your problem is just to Update the Page not to get unsyncronous messages from the server with a bi directional connection. So jou just have to change your page like (please not there is no need to change the files generated by gRPC, I called it Number.proto so my service is named NumberService):

```
async Task SayHello()
{
    //Request via gRPC
    var channel = new Channel(Host + ":" + Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    var client = new this.NumberService.NumberServiceClient(channel);
    var request = new Number{
         identification = "ABC"
    };
    var result = await client.SendNumber(request).RequestAccepted;
    await channel.ShutdownAsync();

    //Update page
    this.Greetmsg = result;
    InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);//Required to refresh page
}
```

**Bi Directional**

For making a continious bi directional connection you need to change the proto file to use streams like:

```
service ChatService {
    rpc chat(stream ChatMessage) returns (stream ChatMessageFromServer);
}
```

This Chant sample is from the https://github.com/meteatamel/grpc-samples-dotnet

The main challenge on this is do divide the task waiting for the gRPC server from the client. I found out that `BackgroundService` is good for this. So create a Service inherited from `BackgroundService` where place the `while` loop waiting for the server in the `ExecuteAsync`method. Also define a Action callback to update the page (alternative you can use an event)

```
public class MyChatService : BackgroundService
{
    Random _random = new Random();

    public Action<int> Callback { get; set; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Replace next lines with the code request and wait for server...
            using (_call = _chatService.chat())
            {
                // Read messages from the response stream
                while (await _call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
                {
                    var serverMessage = _call.ResponseStream.Current;
                    var otherClientMessage = serverMessage.Message;
                    var displayMessage = string.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", otherClientMessage.From, otherClientMessage.Message, Environment.NewLine);
                    if (Callback != null) Callback(displayMessage);
                }
                // Format and display the message
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On the page init and the `BackgroundService` and set the callback:

```
@page "/greeter"
@using System.Threading

<p>Current Number: @currentNumber</p>

@code {
    int currentNumber = 0;
    MyChatService myChatService;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        myChatService = new MyChatService();
        myChatService.Callback = i =>
        {
            currentNumber = i;
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };
        await myChatService.StartAsync(new CancellationToken());
    }
}
```

More information on `BackgroundService` in .net core can be found here: https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-worker-service/

Comment: In that example seems that a request is being repeatedly made to some data provider by that background service. It almost looks like a task. I checked that link and that worker thing really looks like a program to pool something with some updated data. My problem now is that he blazor page does not update the value received from a gRPC service into the singleton that is also linked in the blazor page..

Comment: For the sample you just forgot to call `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` after the value will be updated. But as you say you want to continually update this you should place it in a background worker or something like that. What you need is a bi directional gRPC connection, see https://damienbod.com/2019/03/25/grpc-bi-directional-streaming-with-razor-pages-and-a-hosted-service-grpc-client/ for how that works and place it in the ExecuteAsync Methode. Another way would be SignalR where you can also please the wait in the ExecuteAsync method.

Comment: Hi. Didn't understood what you meant with "For the sample you just forgot to call InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); after the value will be updated."
In this new code i've put the StateHasChanged, but the program never reachs that code.

Comment: In the `GiveNumbers`method of your original post add `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);` at the end so the page is refreshed.

Comment: Ho, that method is in a separated class that inherits from the automatically generated class from the protofile, and overrides it's methods. It has nothing to do with the page being handed to the user by the HTTP service. I have this discussion going on: https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop/issues/201